# How to draw histogram with time data at Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have time data like below.

```
      time
0  0:00:30
1  0:01:34
.
.
```

And I want to draw histogram depends on the time.
For example, this is the x-axis of histogram like 0-8, 9-16, 17-24.
How can I divide and draw it?

I used matplotlib histogram.

```
plt.hist(dailyData['time'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369584/plot-histogram-of-datetime-time-python-matplotlib 
I've already read this, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why does it not work for you?

Comment: It says that 'str' object has no attribute 'hour'...

Comment: Edit your question and include how you used the code. To use that code you need to first convert your data to `datetime` objects.

Comment: without that code, isn't there the other way?

Comment: You will want to convert to `datetime` objects regardless, unless you want to parse out the first 2 digits of every string, convert them to ints and then group them. Use `pd.to_datetime()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, first convert your data to `datetime` objects. Then get only the hours in a list using a list comprehension. Next select your bins and plot.

```
data = pd.to_datetime(dailyData['time'], format="%H:%M:%S") 

hour_list = [t.hour for t in data]
bins = [0,9,17,24]

plt.hist(hour_list,bins)
plt.show()
```

Comment: One more thing please. When the time is 2:10:20, I want to get the full minute like ' 2*60+10" = 130. How can I get this from datetime objects?

Comment: To get a similar list of minutes data you would do something like this: `minute_list = [(t.hour*60+t.minute) for t in data]`